# VueJS set first radiobutton as checked if v-model is empty

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How can i have checked radio button in v-for, if my v-model is empty?

The list of users may be different, so I can't set selectedUserId: 665. I tried to use :checked="index == 0" but it does not work with v-model.

```js
 var radioVue = new Vue({
  el: "#test",
  data: {
   selectedUserId: null,
      users: [{id: 665, name: 'John'}, {id: 1135, name: 'Edward'}, {id: 7546, name: 'David'}]
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <div v-for="(user, index) in users">
 <input type="radio" :value="user.id" v-model="selectedUserId"> {{ user.name }}
  </div>
 <span>{{ selectedUserId}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Found [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/0f2obrg1/). Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use watch for that:

```
watch: {
  selectedUserId: {
    handler(newVal) {
      if (newVal === null || newVal === undefined) {
        this.selectedUserId = this.users[0].id
      }
    },
    immediate: true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for this you can use get/set on computed variable with your v-model

the setter does a standard set while the getter return the wanted users id or if there is not the id of the first user (as in first entry of the array)

```js
var radioVue = new Vue({
  el: "#test",
  data: {
    selectedUserId: 7546,
    users: [{id: 665, name: 'John'}, {id: 1135, name: 'Edward'}, {id: 7546, name: 'David'}]
  },
  computed: {
    checkedUserId: {
      get() {
        // need to use == instead of === because v-model seems to set as string :/
        return this.users.some(user => user.id == this.selectedUserId) ? this.users.filter(user => user.id == this.selectedUserId)[0].id : this.users[0].id
      },
      set(val) {
        // doing a parseInt() here would allow you to use === in get
        this.selectedUserId = val
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <div v-for="user in users">
    <input type="radio" :value="user.id" name="name" v-model="checkedUserId"> {{ user.name }} - {{ user.id }}
  </div>
  <span>{{ selectedUserId}}</span>
  <input type="text" v-model="selectedUserId">
</div>
```